# Hide area name from url in mvc with duplicate controller name in area as well as outside area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

We are using Areas in ASP.NET MVC5 with AttributeRouting to define our routes.

Right now we have "admin" area and one is outside area i.e. use for front-end site

I don't want the /admin in the route.

My question is, how do I hide the Area in my URL so I can call

```
mywebsite.com/home/1
```

instead of

```
mywebsite.com/Admin/Home/1
```

I found solution for this but if i have controller name i.e. "Home" in area and outside area that time it will not work because it make confusion to routing.

So using same controller name in area and outside how can i hide my area name from Url.

**Main Routeconfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
      new[] { "application.Controllers" }
    );
```

**AdminAreaRegistartion.cs**

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Areas/Admin/Controller

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure; you want to let `mywebsite.com/home/1` point to 2 different locations?

Comment: ya.. it is point to admin area controller. but same controller is outside area exists. so may be point to two controller.

Comment: If `mywebsite.com/home/1` points to 2 different locations, how will you distinguish between them? I don't think this is possible unless you some sort of admin cookie or actionfilter to redirect you to a different view.

Comment: Yes.. I also think like this..but I am trying to find solution if found, because already my application is developed and there are many same controllers name exists in area as well as outside area.so for that I m trying to get solution which is not affect my current controllers.

Comment: If you would like to have a different behavior for the same route, then you should create a single action and make the logic in it to do different things depending on user role for instance, instead of creating 2 different actions for same route. If even it would be possible - your colleagues will hate you after that kind of implementation.

Comment: Actually there is a way how to do it, but I will not post it here just to prevent developers from "shitty-code".